# How to detect number keys in a NativeEvent?

Tags: java, javascript, events, gwt

Looking at `com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent extends JavaScriptObject`, how can I detect if the event was a number?
I thought of `Character.isDigit(event.getKeyCode())`, but this would give me an error:

> The method isDigit(char) in the type Character is not applicable for the arguments (int)

How could I else detect his?
I'm using GWT Java for this.

Comment: Where does `Character.isDigit` come from? Is this ActionScript or some other implementation of ECMAScript?

Comment: java.lang.Character. Sorry I should have mentioned the NativeEvent comes from gwt.

Comment: That makes more sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

```
addKeyPressHandler( new KeyPressHandler()
{
  public void onKeyPress( KeyPressEvent event )
  {
   char charCode = event.getCharCode();
   if ( Character.isDigit( charCode ) )
   {
    System.out.println("This is a digit!!!");
   }
  }
}
```

### Solution 2

```
public void onBrowserEvent( com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater )
    {       
        if ( "keypress".equals( event.getType() ) )
        {
            int charCode = event.getCharCode();
            if ( !Character.isDigit( ( char ) charCode ) )
            {
              System.out.println("This is a digit!!!");
            }
        }
        super.onBrowserEvent( context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater );
    }
```

Comment: No, I only have the `NativeEvent`. To be more specific: it's in `onBrowserEvent()` of `EditTextCell`, which only supplies the native event.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I commented above to cast the CharCode to char and forward it to isDigit(). Anyway very useful to have a complete example here.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that I have to make a cast to: `(char) event.getKeyCode();`
This way `isDigit(char)` can be used without problems.